# in pandas how can I groupby weekday() for a datetime column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to filter out weekend data and only look at data for weekdays (mon(0)-fri(4)).  I'm new to pandas, what's the best way to accomplish this in pandas?

```
import datetime
from pandas import *

data = read_csv("data.csv")
data.my_dt 

Out[52]:
0     2012-10-01 02:00:39
1     2012-10-01 02:00:38
2     2012-10-01 02:01:05
3     2012-10-01 02:01:07
4     2012-10-01 02:02:03
5     2012-10-01 02:02:09
6     2012-10-01 02:02:03
7     2012-10-01 02:02:35
8     2012-10-01 02:02:33
9     2012-10-01 02:03:01
10    2012-10-01 02:08:53
11    2012-10-01 02:09:04
12    2012-10-01 02:09:09
13    2012-10-01 02:10:20
14    2012-10-01 02:10:45
...
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
weekdays_only = data[data.my_dt.weekday() < 5]
```

AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'weekday'

but this doesn't work, I haven't quite grasped how column datetime objects are accessed.

The eventual goal being to arrange hierarchically to weekday hour-range, something like:

```
monday, 0-6, 7-12, 13-18, 19-23
tuesday, 0-6, 7-12, 13-18, 19-23
```

Comment: not sure about your use case, but normally you would use `my_dt` as the index by passing `parse_dates=True` and `index_col=<my_dt col>` as keyword arguments to `read_csv` and `read_csv` will return a  `pandasTimeSeries`. Then you can simply do `weekdays = data[data.index.weekday < 5]`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

your call to the function "weekday" does not work as it operates on the index of data.my_dt, which is an int64 array (this is where the error message comes from)

you could create a new column in data containing the weekdays using something like:

```
data['weekday'] = data['my_dt'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday())
```

then you can filter for weekdays with:

```
weekdays_only = data[data['weekday'] < 5 ]
```

I hope this helps

Comment: great! that'll do it... ok, I also noticed that data.my_dt.map() can be used to do the same it seems.  Do you know the difference between using .map() and .apply()?

Comment: In this case they're equivalent. Apply can also do aggregation and other things

Answer (score 10):

Faster way would be to use [`DatetimeIndex.weekday`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday.html), like so:

```
temp = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['my_dt'])
data['weekday'] = temp.weekday
```

Much much faster, especially for a large number of rows. For further info, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21811766/3765319) answer.

Comment: If you are running Pandas 0.15 you can just write `data['my_dt'].dt.weekday`, provided `data['my_dt']` is datetime or timedelta or similar date based format (see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors for more information). If it is not, `data['my_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(data['my_dt'])` will convert it to datetime (you can also specify format and other things in `pd.to_datetime()`, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.tools.to_datetime.html).