# Split datetime64 column into a date and time column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe with the first column being a datetime64 column. How do I split this column into 2 new columns, a date column and a time column. Here is my data and code so far:

```
DateTime,Actual,Consensus,Previous
20140110 13:30:00,74000,196000,241000
20131206 13:30:00,241000,180000,200000
20131108 13:30:00,200000,125000,163000
20131022 12:30:00,163000,180000,193000
20130906 12:30:00,193000,180000,104000
20130802 12:30:00,104000,184000,188000
20130705 12:30:00,188000,165000,176000
20130607 12:30:00,176000,170000,165000
20130503 12:30:00,165000,145000,138000
20130405 12:30:00,138000,200000,268000
...


import pandas as pd
nfp = pd.read_csv("NFP.csv", parse_dates=[0])
nfp
```

Gives:

```
Out[10]: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
         Int64Index: 83 entries, 0 to 82
         Data columns (total 4 columns):
         DateTime     82  non-null values
         Actual       82  non-null values
         Consensus    82  non-null values
         Previous     82  non-null values
         dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(3)
```

All good but not sure what to do from here.

Two points specifically I am unsure about:

1. Is it possible to do this when I read the csv file in the first place? If so, how?
2. Can any one help show me how to do the split once I have performed csv_read?

Also is there anywhere I can look up this kind of information?

Having a hard time finding a detailed reference of the class libraries Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**How to parse the CSV directly into the desired DataFrame:**

Pass a dict of functions to `pandas.read_csv`'s `converters` keyword argument:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT
nfp = pd.read_csv("NFP.csv", 
                  sep=r'[\s,]',              # 1
                  header=None, skiprows=1,
                  converters={               # 2
                      0: lambda x: DT.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d'),  
                      1: lambda x: DT.time(*map(int, x.split(':')))},
                  names=['Date', 'Time', 'Actual', 'Consensus', 'Previous'])

print(nfp)
```

yields

```
        Date      Time  Actual  Consensus  Previous
0 2014-01-10  13:30:00   74000     196000    241000
1 2013-12-06  13:30:00  241000     180000    200000
2 2013-11-08  13:30:00  200000     125000    163000
3 2013-10-22  12:30:00  163000     180000    193000
4 2013-09-06  12:30:00  193000     180000    104000
5 2013-08-02  12:30:00  104000     184000    188000
6 2013-07-05  12:30:00  188000     165000    176000
7 2013-06-07  12:30:00  176000     170000    165000
8 2013-05-03  12:30:00  165000     145000    138000
9 2013-04-05  12:30:00  138000     200000    268000
```

1. `sep=r'[\s,]'` tells `read_csv` to split lines of the csv on the
   regex pattern `r'[\s,]'` -- a whitespace or a comma.
2. The `converters` parameter tells `read_csv` to apply the given
   functions to certain columns. The keys (e.g. 0 and 1) refer to the
   column index, and the values are the functions to be applied.

---

**How to split the DataFrame after performing csv_read**

```
import pandas as pd
nfp = pd.read_csv("NFP.csv", parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True)
temp = pd.DatetimeIndex(nfp['DateTime'])
nfp['Date'] = temp.date
nfp['Time'] = temp.time
del nfp['DateTime']

print(nfp)
```

---

**Which is faster?**

It depends on the size of the CSV. (Thanks to Jeff for pointing this out.)

For tiny CSVs, parsing the CSV into the desired form directly is faster than  using a DatetimeIndex after parsing with `parse_dates=[0]`:

```
def using_converter():
    nfp = pd.read_csv("NFP.csv", sep=r'[\s,]', header=None, skiprows=1,
                      converters={
                          0: lambda x: DT.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d'),
                          1: lambda x: DT.time(*map(int, x.split(':')))},
                      names=['Date', 'Time', 'Actual', 'Consensus', 'Previous'])
    return nfp

def using_index():
    nfp = pd.read_csv("NFP.csv", parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True)
    temp = pd.DatetimeIndex(nfp['DateTime'])
    nfp['Date'] = temp.date
    nfp['Time'] = temp.time
    del nfp['DateTime']
    return nfp

In [114]: %timeit using_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 1.71 ms per loop

In [115]: %timeit using_converter()
1000 loops, best of 3: 914 µs per loop
```

However, for CSVs of just a few hundred lines or more, using a DatetimeIndex is faster.

```
N = 20
filename = '/tmp/data'
content = '''\
DateTime,Actual,Consensus,Previous
20140110 13:30:00,74000,196000,241000
20131206 13:30:00,241000,180000,200000
20131108 13:30:00,200000,125000,163000
20131022 12:30:00,163000,180000,193000
20130906 12:30:00,193000,180000,104000
20130802 12:30:00,104000,184000,188000
20130705 12:30:00,188000,165000,176000
20130607 12:30:00,176000,170000,165000
20130503 12:30:00,165000,145000,138000
20130405 12:30:00,138000,200000,268000'''

def setup(n):
    header, remainder = content.split('\n', 1)
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join([header]+[remainder]*n))

In [304]: setup(50)

In [305]: %timeit using_converter()
100 loops, best of 3: 9.78 ms per loop

In [306]: %timeit using_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 9.3 ms per loop
```

---

**Where can I look up this kind of information?**

1. Sometimes you can find examples in the [Pandas Cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html).
2. Sometimes web searching or searching Stackoverflow suffices.
3. Spending a weekend snowed in with nothing to do but reading the
   [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) will surely help too.
4. Install [IPython](http://ipython.org/). It has tab completion and if you type a `?` after a
   function, it gives you the function's docstring. Those two features
   really help you introspect Python objects quickly. It also tells you in what file the function is defined (if defined in pure Python) -- which leads me to...
5. [Reading the source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas)

Just keep at it. The more you know the easier it gets.

If you give it your best shot and still can't find the answer, post a question on Stackoverflow. You'll hopefully get an answer quickly, and help others searching for the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. It is exactly what I am looking for. Special thanks for the information sources. Coming from C++/C# development finding that learning all these new libraries is harder than I thought it would be!

Comment: FYI try  to_datetime and read_csv with new infer_datetime_format=True ; should be even faster

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks for the info. I added `infer_datetime_format=True`. Where would you use `to_datetime`?

Comment: oh...thought I saw it...nvm then.

Comment: Btw if the the DateTime columns' time component was in the format %H:%M:%S.%f instead how would deal with this part of the code.            1: lambda x: DT.time(*map(int, x.split(':')))}

Comment: just so u know the converters answer will not compete with the index answer if this frame is decently sized ; say 10k rows will prob show the perf matchup is reversed

Comment: @azuric: Given what Jeff has pointed out, you are probably better off using the `DatetimeIndex` solution rather than the converter solution. It will not only be faster for normal-sized CSV, but also avoid date parsing issues since `parse_dates` uses dateutil's flexible date parser.

Comment: Thanks guys this has helped a lot.