# Using pandas groupby to fill in timeseries based up upon weekday and weekend

Tags: datetime, pandas, group-by

Thanks to whoever can help with this:

I have an annual time series at half-hour intervals. There are NaN values littered throughout. What I am looking to do is first fill in the NaN values with the average of the same day of the week within the same month.

This is what I have so far:

```
def fill_mean(VAH_data):                    
    # function which replaces NaN values with the mean of a particular grouping
    return VAH_data.fillna(VAH_data.mean())

VAH_data_filled =\
    VAH_data_rs.groupby([lambda x: x.month, lambda x: x.weekday(), lambda x: x.hour], 
                        group_keys=False).apply(fill_mean)
```

`
This fills in most but there are still gaps ranging in size. I would like to instead implement the weekday() function inside the grouping to generalize between weekdays and weekends.

I found the following thread:
[in pandas how can I groupby weekday() for a datetime column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740672/in-pandas-how-can-i-groupby-weekday-for-a-datetime-column)

but unsure as to how to implement it within group-by.

SOLUTION

I've figured out one way for people to look at:

```
#Create copy of index column to be used to group day types
VAH_data_fill1['date_temp'] = VAH_data_fill1.index

#Create separate column that indicates specific day type
VAH_data_fill1['weekday'] =\
    VAH_data_fill1['date_temp'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday())

#Create a function to differentiate between weekdays and weekends
#Days are defined as: Monday = 0 to Sunday = 6
dayLog = []
def day_differentiate(VAH_data2):
    if VAH_data2 < 5:
        dayLog.append(1)
    else:
        dayLog.append(0)

#Apply differentiate function to sort weekdays and weekends
VAH_data_fill1['weekday'].apply(day_differentiate)

#Add column of logged day types
dayType = {'dayType': pd.Series(dayLog)}
dayType = pd.DataFrame(dayType)
dayType = dayType.set_index(VAH_data_fill1.index)
VAH_data_fill1 = pd.concat([VAH_data_fill1, dayType],axis=1)

VAH_data_fill2 =\
    VAH_data_fill1.groupby([lambda x: x.month, 'dayType', 
                            lambda x: x.hour],            
                           group_keys=False).apply(fill_mean)
```

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: I figured it out....

Comment: Instead of posting the solution as part of the question, turn it into an answer and accept it. [It is considered good form](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)